# How to set "key_ops" parameter in private key as "sign" and public key as "verify" using com.nimbusds.jose.jwk

Tags: java, jwt

```
RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKeyGenerator(2048)
    .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
    .keyID(kid)
    .algorithm(JWSAlgorithm.RS384)
    .generate();
```

The above code generate RSA key. I am having a doubt how to add key_ops parameter in private and public key.

Comment: Which kind of "doubt" do you have?

Comment: I don't know how to display "key_ops" parameter as sign and verify for different key.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How would you like to "display" such a parameter?

Comment: for private key and public key it is required.